# Sequelize join table without selecting

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I'd like to select IDs from a join table in a many-to-many relation in Sequelize, and restrict results based on one of the endpoints. For example:

```
ModelA:
- id
- deleted_at
- is_expired

ModelB:
- id
- deleted_at
- is_active

ModelAToModelB:
- a_id
- b_id
```

I'd like to do something like

```
SELECT id FROM ModelAToModelB ab INNER JOIN ModelB b ON ab.b_id = b.id WHERE ab.id = someA_ID AND b.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

I'm currently do something like

```
const ModelB = require("./modelb")
const ModelAToModelB = require("./modelatob");

ModelAToModelB.findAll({
    where: { id: someA_ID },
    include: [
       {
           model: ModelB,
           where: { deleted_at: null }
       }
    ]
})
```

That seems to work, except then I also get all the data from `ModelB` as well, when all I want is `ModelAToB.id`.

Is there any way to scrap `ModelB`'s data? Or maybe use something from `ModelA` to get just the association IDs?

Answer (score 12):

```
const ModelB = require("./modelb")
const ModelAToModelB = require("./modelatob");

ModelAToModelB.findAll({
    where: { id: someA_ID },
    include: [
       {
           model: ModelB.scope(null), //Prevent the default scope from adding attributes
           where: { deleted_at: null },
           required: true, //Force an inner join
           attributes: [] //Join without selecting any attributes
       }
    ]
})
```